# make http request and if status is forbidden continue, node

Tags: node.js

Here I am making some http requests on links which I filtered in advance. The links are inside an array in string format.

```
for (let link of linkArray) {

    const linkOptions = {
      uri: link,
      resolveWithFullResponse: true,
    };
    linkRequest = await rp(linkOptions);

    //some other actions with linkRequest response
}
```

But of course `the request statuses of the links can be some bad ones` (for example `404 forbidden errors`, status codes basically grater than 300).
Here I don't want the program to be crushed, instead I want to skip the response that is forbidden and continue checking remaining links of `linkArray`.
What I have tried so far:
below the comment I checked the `statusCodes`, if it's some bad one than continue loop iteration.

```
if (assetsRequest.statusCode === 204 || assetsRequest.statusCode >= 300) continue
```

But the request is failing when it's is bad request, in any case without waiting for my checking. Any ideas how to handle this?

p.s. I am using [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program crashes because you do not catch the error.

You should always catch errors, especially if you do error prone process such as http request.

Here i've added try catch

```
for (let link of linkArray) {
    const linkOptions = {
      uri: link,
      resolveWithFullResponse: true,
    };
    try {
      linkRequest = await rp(linkOptions);
    } catch(err) {
      // do something with error or at least log it
      console.log(err);
    }
    //some other actions with linkRequest response
}
```

So when rp() fails, it will go straight to the catch block but does not quit the loop, hence the process continue for other link in the array.